# How does Instagram know which button you clicked without having an ID or Name of the button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

A very random question, I just looked at instagram and when you click that 3 dots on the feed on a following user post, you have multiple options: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDUXA.png

I looked like everyone does, on inspect element and I see that for every button is the same className.

So, how did they know that I've clicked on button 'Go to post' for example?

A example code is this:

```
<button class="testButtonClass">Report this user</button>
<button class="testButtonClass">Go to user profile</button>
<button class="testButtonClass">Cancel</button>
```

I mean they sure use javascript to know which button was clicked, so how can I know that he clicked 'Go to user profile' ?

Btw, using name (example below), it will be more easy, right?

```
<button class="testButtonClass" name="reportUser">Report this user</button>
<button class="testButtonClass" name="viewUserProfile">Go to user profile</button>
<button class="testButtonClass" name="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: My guess is that they have a common event handler function, and it that function they check the text of the button.

Comment: @ControlAltDel they check the ' text ' of the button ? On ' Instagram"s ' level ? Never. They use a framework like ReactJs and use onclick handlers that trigger methods. It can be a single method be common to all items and use refs or for each item a different method used. Eg. `<item onClick={goToProfile} >Go to profile</item>` But surely they don't check for text. Who does that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram uses React JS, which allows you to bind functions without getting a reference to them by ID or class. If you open Instagram on chrome with the [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) extension, you can actually see it uses that.

If you inspect, select the button you want to check, and click [Event Listeners](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/513974634312368129/875836473637761024/unknown.png), you can actually see the `click` event and what happens when it is fired.